Get Icon for any File/Exe on Windows using Python
I tried to find a few answers but only found this exact question on Stack Overflow without any proper answer.
I am trying to build an Alternate Shell to replace the Default Desktop but it wouldn't look good without Icons, so I tried several approaches such as locating the target files of the Shortcuts on Desktop and the ones which target an .exe, I can get those using icoextract module for python but for other generic files such as a Word Document, or simply a Folder, I am unable to get their Icons. They also include apps installed using Microsoft Store which don't directly link to an .exe. Some answers included using registry but did not clearly specify how to do so using Python. This Github Repository includes Desktop Dependency and Desktop Dependency 2 which include my tries until now. So is there and module or some way to get the Icon for any filetype by simply providing its absolute path? (P.S.: customtkinter for GUI is temporary for reference purposes only and plan on using PyQt).

Developing an alternative shell in Python isn't a good idea. Windows Explorer uses a large set of C functions and structures for getting folder listings, file/folder info and icons. Those methods even use a non-printable path system with list of pointers (binary paths, not strings like C:\Windows). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/functions

I know it might not be a good idea to use Python, but I want to improve my Python knowledge by taking on challenging problems like these, I also don't care whether it is less efficient as I like to push Python's limits. Currently if I am unable to find a reliable and easy way to get these icons, I am planning on using an Icon Pack and define the most common file extensions manually and link them with their respective icons.
